# how to identify children input type

Tags: jquery, forms

Basically I have several divs, each contains a question. This question could be presented with either single input, radio buttons or checkboxes.

I want to identify what the input type is, when looping through the divs.

the following code to achieve this doesn't work, just trying to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

```
$(".question").each(function(){

        var type = $(this).children('input').attr("type").val();
        alert(type);
});
```

Comment: define "doesn't work"  does it throw an error?  does it do anything?
I don't think you need .val() on the attr

Comment: well that simply does nothing. I'm assuming because in no way am I narrowing it down to a specific input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the val():

```
  var type = $(this).children('input').attr("type");
```

e.g.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('button').click(function(){$(".question").each(function(){

         var type = $(this).children('input').attr("type");
         alert(type);
        });
      });
  });


 <div class="question">
  <input type="radio">hello</input>
 </div>

 <div class="question">
   <input type="checkbox">hello</input>
 </div>

 <div class="question">
   <input type='text' name='response[4][answer]'></input>
 </div>

 <button>Click</button>
```

Comment: thanks BonyT, this works, however when the div contains a simple text input, the output is 'undefined'. Why would this be?

Comment: you haven't set the type of "text"?

Comment: this from the html source `<input type='text' name='response[4][answer]'>` and it is returning 'undefined'.

Comment: OK - the jquery expression is selecting all children of the node with a class of "question" - in your code, you have lots of non-input type elements as children - you need to include the 'input' selector as in my example

Comment: apologies, that was the wrong jsfiddle, should have been this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6jDR/7/

Comment: you are using children which only selects the immediate descendants - the text input is not an immediate descendant - use find instead.

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2aec/)**

```
$(".question > input").each(function(){
        var type = $(this).attr("type");
        alert(type);
});
```

Comment: thats fine if I wanted to loop through every input in every div, but I don't. I just want to loop through each div, and assess essentially if there hasn't been a response. thanks tho.

Answer (score 1):

`var type = $(this).find("input").get(0).type;`

Answer (score 0):

this should get you going:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).children('input').each(function(){
       alert($(this).attr('type'));   
    });
});
```

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p6F9T/